# When I tapped into the cell, that blue color always stays there?

Tags: uitableview

When I tapped into any cell in tableview, blue color that shows us cell state (yes you tapped in!) always lights up and never disappears even if I go back to same table view through navigation. What's the reason ? I did not change anything with cell options ..

Comment: Do you have any code in viewWillAppear? Show the code you have in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Did you try calling [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES] in your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any errors? Check the console output for debug messages.

Comment: I have no errors. I figured it out by refreshing table view when I returned to same table view. But blue light is not disappearing slightly when I returned. It is just lost. Did you understand what i meant ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

- process the selection of that UITableViewCell through handling didSelectRowAtIndexPath: properly.
- disable the selection of the cell entirely, if you don't want it selectable, by setting the selectionStyle (?) property of the UITableViewCell.

Please let us know,